# IronPython "name 'locals' is not defined" when running in sandbox but not when I run the script directly

Tags: python, ironpython

If I call the `locals` function in an IronPython script sandboxed in this game I'm working on, I get an error "name 'locals' is not defined", but if I call it in a standalone script, it works. What could be deleting the `locals` function from my script context in the sandbox?

edit: added an example script, this script works when I run it during a turn, but when I go to generate the next turn, it crashes saying `str` is not defined.

```
import sys, imp;
import __builtin__ as builtins;
builtins_code = """""";
exec builtins_code in builtins.__dict__;
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Core')
import System
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)
clr.AddReference('FrEee.Core')
import FrEee
import FrEee.Utility
clr.ImportExtensions(FrEee.Utility.Extensions)
from FrEee.Modding import Mod
from FrEee.Game.Objects.Space import Galaxy
from FrEee.Game.Objects.Civilization import Empire
'Generates ' + str(ShieldPointsGenerated) + ' shield points.'
```

The `ShieldPointsGenerated` variable is injected like so:

```
engine.GetBuiltinModule().SetVariable(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

where the key/value pairs are the variable names and values I'm using in the script.

Comment: When you say "running in sandbox", are you referring to a .NET AppDomain, or some IronPython-specific sandbox library? Because I can easily imagine why a sandbox library would hide some of the builtins that can be used to escape that sandbox, like `locals`, but that doesn't seem as likely for a generic .NET thing.

Comment: In an AppDomain, yes.

Comment: By the way, the same thing happens to the `vars` function and even the `str` type...

Comment: OK, presumably something is causing your code to be run in a globals environment that explicitly hides some or all builtins. See the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) docs for how that's done and what it means. Of course it's probably not `exec`, but an IronPython function being called from .NET, and I don't really know the IronPython API, but I assume it works similar to the [CPython C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html), where you can pass in a globals to, e.g., `PyRun_String`, and it works exactly the same as one you pass to `exec`.

Comment: Still running into this issue, but oddly it only happens when I process a turn in my game - if I run the scripts while playing a turn, I get the correct results...